# Python Tkinter Listbox page scroll, activation and selection difficulties

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, listbox

I am building an app using Tkinter on Python and a Listbox.

I am able to use the arrow (up/down) and page (up/down) to move the underline, but the blue highlight stays unmoved.

When I try to get the index, it returnes the number of the blue bar, not the underline.

How do I either...

1) move the blue bar along with the underline so index returnes the expected thing,

2) get the number of the blue bar, not the underline which is what index point to.

```
def PageDn(event):
    w = event.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    print index

lb_cur = tk.Listbox(root, exportselection = False, selectmode="SINGLE")
lb_cur.bind("<Next>", PageDn)
```

Thanks, Mark

Comment: If you set `selectmode` to `"browse"`, does that give you the behaviour you want?

Comment: I just attempted BROWSE vs SINGLE, but no change. Added note, using the mouse, the app works as expected. I am only talking about moving using the keyboard.

Comment: Setting the value to "browse" should have worked, because it's behavior is exactly what you describe. What platform are you running on?

Comment: Win-7. Python for Windows 2.7.12. Sorry, I should know by now that is info that is expected